# TouchJSON and SOAP

Tags: iphone, rest, soap, touchjson

How can i make a SOAP call using TouchJson?
it just work fine with REST call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing some fundamentals here. SOAP is XML based. JSON is an alternative markup to XML that's more compact. Making a "REST call" simply means you are requesting a resource. If the resource is returned in a JSON format, it makes sense that it works for you using TouchJSON. If you are calling out to a SOAP web service, however, it is not going to return JSON but rather XML that needs to be made into an object using a SOAP library.

Best regards.